# Change bowerFiles() injection path in Gulp task

Tags: javascript, build, gulp

I have the following Gulp task:

```
gulp.task('bowerinstall', function() {
    gulp.src('app/index.html')
        .pipe($.inject(gulp.src(bowerFiles(), {read: false}), {name: 'bower'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(['dist/', 'app/']));
});
```

This task looks at my index.html and injects bower files into it. This works fine, however it injects the following paths into my index.html:

```
<script src="/app/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
```

It's good that the task has identified the correct resource to inject into my application, but I'd like it to inject the following instead:

```
<script src="bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
```

Is there a way to modify my gulp task to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following line:

```
    .pipe($.inject(gulp.src(bowerFiles(), {read: false}), {name: 'bower'}))
```

Add the option `relative: true`, eg:

```
    .pipe($.inject(gulp.src(bowerFiles(), {read: false}), {name: 'bower', relative: true}))
```

This is covered by the documentation:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject#injecting-files-relative-to-target-files